# Simplify $2(\cos^2 x - \sin^2 x)^2 \tan 2x$

Tags: algebra-precalculus, trigonometry

Simplify: $$2(\cos^2 x - \sin^2 x)^2 \tan 2x$$ After some sketching, I arrive at: $$2 \cos 2x \sin2x$$
Now according to the answer sheet, I should simplify this further, to arrive at $\sin 4x$. But how do I derive the latter from the former? Where do I start? Hoe do I use my double-angle formulas to arrive there?

Comment: Hint: $\sin(2u) = 2\cos(u)\sin(u)$. What is $u$ in this case?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Notice,  using double angle identity $\cos^2A-\sin^2A=\cos 2A$, one should get

$$2(\cos^2x-\sin^2x)^2\tan 2x$$
$$= 2\cos^2 2x\tan 2x$$
$$= 2\cos^2 2x\left(\frac{\sin 2x}{\cos 2x}\right)$$
$$= 2\sin 2x\cos 2x$$
 using double angle identity $2\sin A\cos A=\sin 2A$,
$$=\sin 2(2x)$$$$=\color{red}{\sin 4x}$$

Comment: Sorry, there was a typo in the initial post.

Comment: Alright, so I have made correction accordingly

Answer (score 2):

$2\cos(2x)\sin(2x)=\sin(2(2x))=\sin(4x)$

Comment: Yeah, this just doesn't explain why I can do this. I know $2 \cos x \sin x = \sin 2x$, but how do I get from your first step to the second. This is not obvious for me. Would $2 \cos 3x \sin 3x = \sin 6x$?

Comment: First step: use $2x$ instead of $x$ in the sine double angle formula
Second step: $2*2x=4x$  
Yes, $2 \cos 3x \sin 3x = \sin 6x$

Answer (score 1):

Use $$\cos^2x-\sin^2x=\cos2x$$ and $$\tan A=\dfrac{\sin A}{\cos A}$$